# If P is satisfiable and Q is satisfiable, is P^Q satisfiable?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, education

This question is confusing me,

> Is the following statement true?
>
> If P is satisfiable and Q is satisfiable then P∧Q is satisfiable.

I originally thought this was true because when drawing a truth table I find that if P and Q are true, then P∧Q is true too, but my answer sheet says that the statement is false. Why is that?

Comment: Does P^Q stand  for $P\land Q$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes it does, I wasn't sure how to write that symbol sorry

Comment: Is $x>0$ satisfiable? Is $x<0$ satisfiable? Is $x>0\land x<0$ satisfiable?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Ah I see, I didn't think about it like that

Answer (score 1):

Consider $Q = \neg P$, but $P$, $Q$ both satisfiable.